# How to make the app ask for login when a user is not logged in. In KivyMD

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I am making a Music App using Kivy rather KivyMD in Python.
I want to make the app to ask for login when the app has been opened for first time in the mobile or opened after a logout.
Please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get a feeling on how to contribute. You should at least make an own attempt to get your task done and share the code here. Even if you don't have a good knowledge about Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Kivy, but if you have your login written in Python:

Create a `bool` that is set to `true` whenever the user logs in and `false` when logged out and on default (for the first time opening the app). Then, on startups, check the bool value with an `if` statement, and if the `bool` is `false`, prompt a login. Something like this (bear in mind, I'm not the best with Python):

```
bool loggedIn = False;

def LogIn():
    #other login stuff
    loggedIn = True
          
def LogOut():
    #other login stuff
    loggedIn = True

def StartUpFunction():
    if loggedIn == False:
        LogIn()
```

Comment: That Idea was pretty good. I could not think of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in Kivy and on mobile,
but for webpages you save a usertoken encrypted in the localstorage of your browser.
I would use a file, where I add and delete this token
and check the file (or Database) every time you start the app